# Babel + nodejs TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, importerror

I'm trying to export/import a bunch of files in nodejs using babel.
I never has a problem doing so in react projects or typescript libraries, but there's something wrong here obviously related to babel.

I have a folder exporting some files in its `index.js` like so :

```
export { default as Foo } from './Foo'
export { default as Bar } from './Bar'
...
```

There's an `export default` in each one, of course.

When I try to import some or all of them in another file like so :

```
import { Foo } from '../foobar'
// or
import * as foobar from '../foobar'
```

Here's what I got :

```
/build/dist/foobar/index.js:9
    return _Foo.default;
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined
```

My babel config is :

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-root-import", {
      "rootPathSuffix": "src"
    }],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few days back tried to achieve the same. Here is the  way it worked for me
The correct way to export is in index.js:

```
import {Foo} from './Foo/';
import {Bar} from './Bar/';


export { Foo };
export { Bar };
```

In Main.js

```
import {Foo} from './path-to-index.js'
```

Comment: `import {Foo}` will import a named export, not the default one. Plus this is redundant to import first then export it, while you're not supposed to have to do that with ES6.

Comment: I think, Basically, what you are doing here is you importing all your module in a common index.js file. It helps you to further refer these components in another module. This is the way it works.